# Why does firebase fetch function duplicate, so to speak, items it is retrieving?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the bellow firebase fetch method.

The problem is that it will double values for no reason. So for example if in the first "loop" the value is media1 then in the next loop it will also say media1 even though at the point of this node there is only one thing... media1.

**How can I solve this?**

```
var mediaTheUserLikes = [String]()
var num = 0

func getYourLikesForThisPost() {
    mediaTheUserLikes.removeAll()
    ref.child("YourLikes").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child((selectedPost?.user.userID)!).child(postID!).observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in
        if self.mediaTheUserLikes.count > 0 && self.mediaTheUserLikes[self.num] != snap.key {
            self.mediaTheUserLikes.append(snap.key)
        } else if self.mediaTheUserLikes.count == 0 {
            self.mediaTheUserLikes.append(snap.key)
        }
    }
}
```

My solution as seen above does not seem to work.

Comment: What loop? Why do you have an `if else` clause when you do the same in both cases? And why use the size of the array to determine what to do with the response?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think by 'loop' they are referring the the observe being .childAdded which will 'loop' over all of the child nodes within postID. However what they are trying to do is very unclear. Additionally `in the first loop the value is media1` but the code doesn't access *value* and the Firebase structure is not included in the question. There's a logic issue as well; `self.mediaTheUserLikes[self.num]` will always point to the first index (0), which would always be snap.key. Can you clarify and update the question with what your attempting to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `getYourLikesForThisPost`, you're attaching an observer to a node. That observer stays active until you remove it, or until it gets cancelled by Firebase, or until the app exits. My guess is that none of those things happen when you see the behavior you're describing, so that means you have previous observers that are still active.

Given the way you've name your method, it is likely that you actually only want to get the data once, and then stop observing it. In that case you're better of [using `observeSingleEvent(of: .value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once):

```
func getYourLikesForThisPost() {
    mediaTheUserLikes.removeAll()
    ref.child("YourLikes").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
      .child((selectedPost?.user.userID)!).child(postID!)
      .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
          if self.mediaTheUserLikes.count > 0 && self.mediaTheUserLikes[self.num] != snap.key {
            self.mediaTheUserLikes.append(snap.key)
          } else if self.mediaTheUserLikes.count == 0 {
            self.mediaTheUserLikes.append(snap.key)
          }
        }
    }
}):
```

Some of the changes:

- This code uses `observeSingleEvent(of:`, which means the data is read only once and the observer is then immediately removed by the Firebase SDK.
- This code observes `.value` instead of `.childAdded`, which means the snapshot you get back can contain multiple child nodes. For this reason it loops over `snapshot.children`.